# workflow activity throws exception when creating from library with Enterprise library

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, enterprise-library

I have very simple two test projects. One is the library (TestClassLibrary) that consist only simple workflow activity like MyTestActivity.xaml. Another project (TestUnitProject) is the unit project that consist one method with one test line
var test = new TestClassLibrary.MyActivities.MyTestActivity();
It working fine.

BUT if i add by way of nuget assemblies from Enterprise Library into my library (TestClassLibrary) I always get runtime exception

like

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What could be causing this?  The library exists, as far as I know.

PS: Workflow 4.0, Enterprise Library 5.0, Visual Studio 2012

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).